# Between function is giving me a number that is not in between

Tags: mysql

Im trying to make a java app that ask you for ip then it splits the ip by the dots and then send a command to mySQL database, you can see the command bellow.
Even though the first ip is not in between the last it outputs it to me

```
SELECT xd.city, ip_start, ip_end
FROM customIpAndCity as xd
WHERE xd.ip_start_1 = ('2') and  ('114') BETWEEN ip_start_2 AND ip_end_2
        and ('144') BETWEEN ip_start_3 AND ip_end_3     and ('106') BETWEEN ip_start_4 AND ip_end_4;
```

```
                           START               END
Prague,                    2.114.144.0,        2.114.144.7
Russia,                    2.114.144.104,      2.114.144.111
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

I have tryed to google it but there isnt any other mySQL function that does the same.

Comment: you need to edit the question and show the complete table DDL, and example data for the table

Answer (score 1):

It's comparing the values alphabetically, not as integers.

This is false:

```
106 BETWEEN 0 AND 7
```

But this is true:

```
'106' BETWEEN '0' AND '7'
```

Because '1' is between '0' and '7' alphabetically, the condition is satisfied.

To solve this, you could store the individual IP numbers as integers and compare them to an integer argument.

Or if you store them as strings, store them with zero-padding, so you compare:

```
'106' BETWEEN '000' AND '007'
```

Or learn about IP netmasking, so you can compare IP addresses without breaking them into parts.